# OpenCV: Image Processing, What specific function this code performs?

Tags: python, ibm-watson

In testing Images in my Custom classifier created using `IBM Watson package` and `OpenCV`, I got confused with the following code:

```
json_classes = json_result['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]['classes']
```

Please help in understanding the above line of code.

Comment: Please describe in more details or context of the code

Comment: Although missing significant information about issue. Speaking from IBM Watson Package view, This json_classes = json_result['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]['classes'] returns classes it detected/classified with score